# Suspend system before login

Tags: linux, debian, login, sleep, kde

I'm using `debian stretch` and `KDE`. In the settings I have specified that pressing the power button suspends the system. That works great, when I'm logged in. However it does not suspend the system on the login screen. 
If I accidentally wake up the system, I want to send it right back to sleep without having to log in first. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Which login manager do you have? `lightdm` ? `kdm` ? ...

Comment: I'm not really sure, I'll check once my computer is back up. The initial login is also messed up. When I log in, it tries to load something, fails and then loads the usual `KDE` environment. Any tips on how to clean that up would be appreciated!

Comment: Workaround posted... _Easyness_ is an arbitrary concept... BTW it is not possible to set from the BIOS too (it is Motherboard dependent)?

Comment: Updated answer, I think you should find something working for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: Change or set the display manager

You can install `lightdm` as display manager even with KDE <sup>[[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146320/how-do-i-install-kde-and-retain-lightdm-as-a-login-manager)]</sup>.
Indeed it is stated <sup>[[2](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Display_Managers)]</sup> that

> `lightdm` does support suspend on lid closure independently as a built in function. It will work with all greeters. The greeters also **have a button to initiate suspend or hibernate manually**.

So, as simpler workaround, you can install it and suspend the computer closing the lid or clicking the suspend button.

---

#### Solution 2: logind.conf

You can try to change the default line in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff    # default
HandlePowerKey=suspend      # your choice note: uncomment it deleting the `#`
```

---

#### Ad Nauseam...

In general it is possible to remap each key of the keyboard.

- If you are able to do from the bios... well it will work with each operative system
- Since you want that it works without logging in kde or gnome, it is convenient to find a cosy display manager (kdm, lxdm, slim, xdm, **`lightdm`**, gdm...) check for them...
  (I know it is the solution 1).
- You can remap each key of the keyboard,

  - with `xmodmap` <sup>[[3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106468/remapping-power-key-to-delete)]</sup>

    > xmodmap - utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X
  - for example <sup>[[4](https://askubuntu.com/a/66731/196535)]</sup> with  `dconf-tools` you can set the action for the power button press (that I think you have done in KDE, but there is the risk that the display manager didn't get it).
  - with `gsettings` <sup>[[5](https://askubuntu.com/a/580904/196535)]</sup> you can remap by commandline (and put as one of the duty of the startup)

Comment: Ideally I would like to use sulution 2 as I don't have to install additional software. I found and edited the `logind.conf` file, but I still can't suspend the system from the login screen. Any idea why? I found out, that I'm using the `gdm` display manager.

Comment: Check in the BIOS, it's the 1st loaded and it can override some behaviour. BTW in [[ref. 2](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Display_Managers#Comparison_of_Features)] it is stated _"__gdm__ does support suspend on lid closure but it requires gnome-power-manager to be installed. When configuring gnome-power-manager check the use as default box and the same settings will be used by gdm. "_ Since you are using KDE, you can incur in compatibility problem (or massive installation) when you ask gnome components. I still suggest to try with `lightdm`: it's only the _"welcome and login screen"_...